# How to url encode data in Java

Tags: java, python, gson, urlencode

So Im trying to translate a working python code into Java. One of the steps required is to url encode the data. But when I encode the data in Java it looks different than the one in encoded in Python.

In one of the block of Python code theres this:

```
    data = {'request-json': json}
    print('Sending form data:', data)

    data = urlencode(data)
    data = data.encode('utf-8')

    print('Sending data:', data)
```

The Output

> Sending form data: {'request-json': '{"apikey": "xewpjipcpovwiiql"}'}

The output after being encoded

> Sending data: b'request-json=%7B%22apikey%22%3A+%22xewpjipcpovwiiql%22%7D'

So this is what im trying to do in Java. As you can imagine Java is more involved. I used gson to convert to Json

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    
    API_Key key = new API_Key("xewpjipcpovwiiql");
    String jsonInputString = gson.toJson(key);
    
    Data data = new Data(key);
    String request_form = gson.toJson(data);
    
    System.out.println(request_form);
    String urlencoded = URLEncoder.encode(request_form,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    
    System.out.println(urlencoded);
```

The output:

> Sending form data: {"request-json":{"apikey":"xewpjipcpovwiiql"}}

The output of the encoded string:

> %7B%22requestjson%22%3A%7B%22apikey%22%3A%22xewpjipcpovwiiql%22%7D%7D

So they dont look the same so why are they coming differently ? How do I get the same python encoded String in Java ? I noticed in Python it used a combination of single and double quotes and in Java its only Double quotes so I dont know if that makes a difference.

Thank You!

Comment: It seems the input is not the same - there is a blank in the python data that is not in the java data. Also, the braces are different. Your java example includes outer braces, your python example doesn't.

Comment: I noticed that too but I highly doubt thats the issue. Also what do you mean python doesnt have outer braces ? They both look the same to my eyes

Answer (score 1):

On the Python side: The `data.encode('utf-8')` call is not necessary or at least the documentation describes with a different intention compared to this use https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode (and that's why there's a **b'** at the beggining).
The outer brackets are missing because it is interpreting request-json as the URL parameter name (it may be easier to understand if you add a second property at the json's top/first property level, you'll see you end with `request-json=%7B%22apikey%22%3A+%22xewpjipcpovwiiql%22%7D&second-property=<second-property-value>`).

On the Java side: the `request_form` is being completely interpreted as a single value to encode so you can put the encoded value as part of some parameter in a URL, as in: `https://host:port?some-parameter-name=%7B%22requestjson%22%3A%7B%22apikey%22%3A%22xewpjipcpovwiiql%22%7D%7D`